# My 3954abg wifi card wont connect

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Lenovo 3000 n100 laptop. Running lspci in a terminal program, I discovered my wifi card is an Intel Pro/Wireless 3954abg.  The wifi card has been recognized, but will not connect.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, I have better luck with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above the line exit 0, add the line:

```
iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Proofread carefully, save and close gedit.